# jQuery: Ajax request abort in Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have the following problem in Chrome: if I click anchor at page during ajax request (which redirects me to other page), error handler is invoked. I'd like to determine whether it is real error or not.

- abort handler is not invoked
- error is empty
- xhr.status is 0
- xhr.statusText is "error"

Code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        ...
    },
    abort: function () {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Are your ajax request async ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event to abort all request before page is unloaded. This way you will get `status = 'abort'` instead of `status = 'error'` in `error: function(xhr, status, error){}`.

```
var request;

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if(request !== undefined) {
        request.abort();
    }
}

request = $.ajax({ ... });
```

Example I've tested this solution on:

http://jsfiddle.net/vLrYm/7/